# Encapsulation: can a higher protocol encapsulate a lower protocol?

Tags: networking, tunnel

I've heard someone say that a protocol higher up the osi model can encapsulate a lower protocol.

As far as I know, personally, a protocol can only encapsulate a same-level protocol or one at a higher level, i.e. you couldn't have Ethernet carrying ip, which in turn has another Ethernet frame encapsulated (and then IP, and the whole stack).

Could some clear the air?

Comment: I have seen, as a proof-of-concept, IP encapsulated in MIME, attached to emails, delivered over SMTP.

Comment: Thanks for the question that allowed me to reach the 15K milestone ;)

Comment: SSL VPNs are a well known example of this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, encapsulation hide the details of what is encapsulated and doesn't really care about the payload nature.

[VxLAN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7348) is a sensible example of this, with layer2 (VLAN) being encapsulated in layer 4 (UDP).

Comment: Some other examples:  [IP over DNS](https://code.kryo.se/iodine/); or IP over PPP over SSH; or [Ethernet over HTTPS](https://www.softether.org/).

Comment: You may also hear this concept called tunnelling.

Comment: It sucks that you can't encapsulate PoE over TCP/IP though...

Comment: @Dai yeah 802.3at over IP over 802.11...

Comment: You can, but the frame size limitations are killer in that particular application.

Answer (score 9):

Consider a package delivery service, like UPS or DHL.   They don't care what's inside the box - they just make sure it gets to its destination. 
Similarly, the protocol doesn't care what the payload is.  It doesn't have to be a higher layer.

The idea of a layered protocol model is that the "payload" of a layer can be anything.    @JFL gave one example.  IPSec VPN, MPLS, GRE, L2TP, Geneve, are others.

Comment: So one could, for example, ship a toy UPS truck via DHL.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The VPN example would be UPS truck delivering a (real, perhaps smaller) UPS truck with packages inside.

Comment: @JoL Perhaps more realistic analogy would be like how Airbus might uses [Airbus Beluga](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga) to carry another Airbus aircraft fuselage or whole wing section so they can be reassembled elsewhere.

Comment: @JoL It's not a big truck. It's a series of tubes.

Comment: @J... But the bandwidth of a UPS truck full of hard disks slowly rolling across the country is way higher than even a decent amount of fibre lines